# Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x + a_2x^2+..+a_nx^n$. $a_n\neq0$ $[1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, polynomials, taylor-expansion

Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x + a_2x^2+..+a_nx^n$.  $a_n\neq0$     $[1]$

I have that

[image]

Now I want this Taylor polynomial to be $x-x_0$ instead of $x$ degrees.

With binomial formula we have $x^m=[(x-x_0)+x_0]^m=\sum_{k=0}^{m}C_m^k(x-x_0)^k(x_0)^{m-k}$ $[2]$

And then in my book is written that putting $[2]$ into $[1]$ we get  $P(x)=b_0+b_1(x-x_0) + b_2(x-x_0)^2+..+b_n(x-x_0)^n$.

Can you explain me how we get this.

Comment: What are $b_0,b_1,b_2\ldots,$?

Answer (score 1):

After plugging [2] into [1], you think of it as a polynomial in $(x-x_0)$, so each $b_i$ will be the result of grouping terms of equal powers of $(x-x_0)$. Since $x_0$ is a constant, each $b_i$ will be a function of $a_i, C^k_m, x_0^i$. Explicitely:

$$b_i:=\sum_{m=0}^na_mC_{m}^i(x_0)^{m-i}$$